# What set is this head from?

Tags: set-identification

[image: This is a head I came across in my Lego bin.]

Could somebody tell me what set this head was used in. I swore it came from an Indiana jones set, but after looking it up I guess not.

Answer (score 2):

This is part [3626bpb0402](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626bpb0402&in=S):

[image: part image]

This part is present in six sets, but if you are getting it confused with something from Indiana Jones, my bet would be on it coming from this Prince of Persia set ([7573 Battle of Alamut](http://brickset.com/sets/7573-1/Battle-of-Alamut)):

[image: 7573]

Here's the complete minifig with that head from the set:

[image: Minifig image]

Here's the [list of other sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626bpb0402&in=S) if that isn't the right one.